# Playwright opens cmd

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-dotnet

When I run a playwright code in C#, it opens up many cmd windows:
[image]

This is the code I use:

```
using (var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync())
                    {
        var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions() { Headless = true }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var browserPageOptions = new BrowserNewPageOptions() { JavaScriptEnabled = true  };
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync(browserPageOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await page.GotoAsync(URL).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await page.WaitForRequestFinishedAsync();
        var SourceCode = await page.ContentAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await page.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await browser.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are probably running Playwright v1.31.0

That had a defect in that caused [cascading cmd windows to appear](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/21093).  That has been fixed in v1.31.1

Comment: A fix for .NET gets released soon.